# Create Function Teradata

Tags: function, teradata

I want to create a small function (or like) which will take parameters and return result of excuting teradata sql statement. Purpose of this is to convert repeated using SQL into function which can be used into SELECT statement. 
Please point me into right direction. Create Function in teradata requires C/C++ compilation which is too much effort after looking at use of required function.

Answer (score 2):

Passing parameters to SQL can be done using a CREATE MACRO, but those can't be used in a SELECT.

SQL-UDFs are limited to simple scalar functions in Teradata, i.e. no SELECTs, etc.

If you need a more complex function (table or [window] aggregate) you must write it in C or Java.

Comment: I concur with dnoeth - a Teradata MACRO sounds like it would be the ideal candidate for what you are trying to accomplish.